# JqGrid rowNum in pagination not working right

Tags: jqgrid

...
    rowNum: 10,
        pager: '#mypager',
        rowList: [10,20,30]
...

In a table that has more than 10 records, it shows them all and says page 1 of 0, even though the `rowNum` is set to 10. If I choose from the drop-down list 20 than it shows the correct number, even if I select 10 afterwards it again shows the right number of rows. But not on the first visit. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling this solves the problem:

```
jQuery("#tableToGrid").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the initial property isn't getting set correctly, try deleting out the line and redoing it?

```
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
```

Comment: Ah, I think it is where you declare your pager (possibly) try moving your pager declaration below the rowList, and in my pager declaration I include a `$` when identifying the element which is the pager.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you fill the grid in a wrong way. For example if you would use `addRowData` you can include more rows as the value of `rowNum`.

In any way you should include more full code which you use to create the grid and describe how you fill the data in the grid.

Comment: The code is pretty simple:  $(function () {
    tableToGrid("#mytable", {rowNum: 10,
    pager: '#mypager',
    rowList: [10,20,30]
});
});

Comment: @echo: I recommended you before don't use `tableToGrid`. It uses `addRowData` (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.tbltogrid.js#L98)) which is the slowest way to fill the grid and which has many other disadvantages. The problem which you asked is one from there. `tableToGrid` is **not part of main jqGrid code**. It's **old plugin** to jqGrid (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.tbltogrid.js#L3)) created *before* version 3.7 jqGrid which started to support local data.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question and help me with filling the JqGrid?  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356082/how-to-fill-the-jqgrid-data-with-these-records)

Comment: @echo: I am not PHP developer. You need just either use `datatype: "json"` and provide `url` which returns data from the database in JSON format or to use `datatype: "json"` and fill all data for jqGrid in JavaScript variable which you use as input per `data` parameter of jqGrid.